# append html elements to DOM by background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to append the same html elements to the current TAB's document DOM.
I want these html extended elements to live "forever", so I want to built them once, and append them on every page load by the content script.

I was thinking to place the createElement commends at the background page.
Then for every web page load, I want the  content script to  communicate with the background script, so it will append them to the current TAB document DOM.
Is that good practice?
My problem is that I don’t know how to append html elements to the DOM from the background page.
Can you please help?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like a browser action popup?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work. The background page lives in one process, the tab in the other - you cannot send objects from one to the other, only text data (objects sent are automatically converted to JSON). So your best chance is: build everything together in the background page, then get `innerHTML` of your element and send this text to the content script whenever necessary. The content script should then create a new element and set its `innerHTML` to the value it received.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir Palant for you answer, but maybe you can tell me how can i build an interface which will live forever and to place it above every html page by icon click event? many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in content script because "content scripts" are scripts which run in an environment between a page and the Chrome extension. [see this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#videos). remember these scripts will loaded on every page load and they won't affect already opened tabs.
 as an example you can add external scripts like this

```
var theScript = document.createElement('script');
theScript.src = "http://mybwesite.com/static/js/myscript.js"
document.body.appendChild(theScript);
```

as long as you've added it's permissions in manifist:

```
"permissions": [
     "activeTab",
     "tabs",
      "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["js/contentscript.js"]
      }
    ]
```